# My $_SESSION['vars'] don't seem to work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using a `$_SESSION['loggedIn']= true` that does not seem to be saved.
I use `session_start()` before I save it . I can echo the variable straight after and is set, but, as soon as I change the page, the variable is gone. I also use `session_start()` before I read it in the other page...

Now, I have a .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$  index.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```

ok.. So this is index.php

```
@session_start();

define("x_app", "1");

define('X_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));

require_once X_BASE.'/config/config.php';

include "classes/browser.php";

$browser = new Browser();

$browser->setBrowserCookie();

$_SESSION['browser'] = $browser;

$_SESSION['language'] = "english";

//Getting View

$v = explode('/', $_GET['v']);

$view = $v[0];



After this I load the view..
In this case Login, which is loaded by a require function




defined('x_app') or die;

require('helper.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];

$password = $_POST['password'];



if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true){

    //Redirect to my portfolio landing page

}

else{ //Not Logged In


    //Process Form
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

        $xLogin = new X_Login();

        if($xLogin->login($email, $password) == true){

            echo 'User is logged In';

            //@session_start() ---> should I put this here again? Don't think so...
            // ! This is the variable that I can't save 
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;

                    // ! I have an echo here but if change the page, it gets lost
            echo 'session->'.$_SESSION['loggedIn'];

        }else{

            echo 'User is not logged in';

        }

    }
    //Error in Form

    elseif(!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['password'])){

        $error = "Login Error";

        include('views/default.php');

    }


}
```

This is the cookie function

public function setBrowserCookie(){

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['verifyUser'])){  

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ub = $this->getBrowser(); 

@setcookie("verifyUser", $ip.$ub, time()+31536000);

}
```

}

Could  this be affecting the path where the session variables are saved? If so, how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is the session cookie being set?

Comment: Can you post your testing code please

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rules cannot affect the path where the variables are saved, since the path for saving those is not handled by the web server, but by the operation system. It is hard to say what is the cause for your problem, since you don't provide much information about your program code. My guess would be, that there is a problem on how the session id is passed from one request to the next (there are actually many ways the session ID can be lost, including cases where mixing of cookie and url-based session IDs are involved, or mixing of POST and GET variables in a form, mixed with a SID parameter -- those can even be browserspecific).

Post some more information about the way you pass your session id, so we might be able to find a problem there.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now...

Tandu, you solve the problem!

Basically, I checked if the cookie was being saved, as you said, and I realized that it was not being saved. Because I was calling @setCookie(...), I couldn't see this before...

The reason for not being saved was on the first line of the index.php file. There was a comment there, but instead of // (php comment) my work colleague used <!-- --> (html) so the headers were being sent before... :-S

Thanks a lot for your help guys. 
This problem made me go crazy for 2 hours... but now is gone :D

Answer (score -1):

Check the diskspace of the website. My client had been uploading photo's ever since I built him his website and the moment the hosting space ran out he couldn't log in anymore. Turned out the session could not be stored because of that.